# Android market selling upgrades

Tags: android

Im new to android development and I have a question about selling in the google android market. How do you sell upgrades to customers?  For example if I had a free app that I would only allow the app to run for x number of minutes before updating and then have a paid version that would not have the limit. Do I have to have to publish 2 versions of the app or is there a way within the app to allow them to "unlock" the app?  What about premium content like extra features?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you're describing, you can also use in-app billing.
After the trial period, you can popup a message saying the trial is over and asking the user to pay to continue using it.
More info on in-app billing here: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Of course, another option would be to have 2 different versions (with 2 package names) - one for the trial and one for the paid version.